# How to detect a switch in data and do something?

Tags: java, android

So i have this code below:

```
public static String getBSSID(Context context){ 
    WifiManager wifiManager;
    List<ScanResult> results;
    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    wifiManager = (WifiManager)  context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    String essidPrefix = MainFragment.configuration.getEssidPrefix();
    String bssid = null;
    results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
    for(ScanResult scanResult : results){
        String scanWifi = scanResult.SSID;
       if(scanWifi.startsWith(essidPrefix)){
          ids.add(scanResult.BSSID);
          bssid = TextUtils.join(",",ids);

       }

    }
    return bssid;
```

When i detect a certain Wifi BSSID, it will return its BSSID, when it doesnt detect a certain Wifi BSSID, it returns null, what i want to do is when i detect a change from null to not null in BSSID , do something, how should i construct this?

**EDITS**

```
   public static String getBSSID(Context context){
   final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
   final String essidPrefix = MainFragment.configuration.getEssidPrefix();
   final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
   if(wifiManager != null){
       wifiManager.startScan();
   }

   final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
   filter.addAction(wifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);


   final List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();

   final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           ids.clear();
           results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            for(ScanResult scanResult : results){
                String scanSSID = scanResult.SSID;
                if(scanSSID.startsWith(essidPrefix)){
                    ids.add(scanResult.BSSID);
                    configuration.setScanBssid(TextUtils.join(",",ids));

                }
            }
       }
   };
   if(wifiManager != null){
       context.registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
   }


   return configuration.getScanBssid();
}
```

Comment: Use Handler-Runnable to repeat the function getBSSID() after some interval of time  and then check if the BSSID is not null every time then do your job.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to bear in mind that in order to detect something changed you will have to keep a record of how it was before, to compare.

You can store a previous result from your method and compare. It would help you if you directly returned the list. Also, consider that a `Set` would help you quickly find what has been added new or removed.

Finally, if you're planning to stick to returning the comma separated `String`, use `TextUtils.join` outside of the `for` loop; you'll see the result is the same, however, more efficient.

Comment: Any suggestions how to store the previous result?

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is wrong. You should use `BroadcastReceiver` in order to handle updated list of the WiFi access points. Once you call `wifiManager.getScanResults()`, then you cannot be sure if it's `null` or not. You should update list of the acces points, once you get it from the device. Check out the code snippet below.

```
final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

if(wifiManager != null) {
    wifiManager.startScan();
}

final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION);
filter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);

final List<ScanResult> accessPoints = new ArrayList<>();

BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // you can handle list of the access points here...
        accessPoints.clear();
        accessPoints.addAll(wifiManager.getScanResults());

        // optionally you can call wifiManager.startScan() 
        // to continuosly receive updated list of the access points
    }
}

if(wifiManager != null) {
    context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
} else {
    // optionally log error here...
}
```

I haven't tested if it code works, but I think it should. At least you have general idea of the approach here. You can adjust it to your needs by playing around with the `List` depending on the result you want to achieve (e.g. add new APs only, collect everything what your received and then filter it, etc.).

You can also check my library, which helps to solve this problem:

https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveWiFi/

Comment: where should i return my String?

Comment: Once you have `accessPoints` as a List filled with data within a `BroadcastReceiver`, then you can convert this list to `String` or anything you want. Please note, receiving a list of access points is asynchronous operation and your application should wait for receiving them (it is done by `BroadcastReceiver`).

Comment: i see.. could you explain the purpose of placing startscan on the top and registering the receiver at the bottom?

Comment: i tried to do your method i got a returned value of null, check my edits

Comment: I placed startScan twice because if it will be invoked once, you'll get results only once. If that's your case, you can skip the second startScan method call.